# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier - Storyboard id set but still not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have to created a segue programmatically however when I click on the button the view controller does not change to the next, Storyboard ID is set and still not working. Am I missing any other checks in order to make this work?

Please see code below:

```
EntryViewController *entryController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"go"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:entryController animated:YES];
```

its driving me mad. Thanks

Comment: Is 'self.storyboard' set or is it nil?

Comment: @Wain it is likely set to nil because I havent set it, where do I set the storyboard to self?

Answer (score 35):

Inside my viewDidLoad I have placed the button which calls goldStarOpen:

```
UIButton *btnTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnTwo.frame = CGRectMake(250, 20, 40, 40);
[btnTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(goldStarOpen) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnTwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GoldStar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btnTwo];
```

Inside goldStarOpen I have code which is almost identical to yours.

```
- (void)goldStarOpen
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GoldStar"];
    [self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

goldStarOpen activates a ViewController in the storyboard.

You may need to set the Storyboard ID of the View Controller you are trying to load. This is located in the inspector, just below where you assign a custom class to your view controller.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem, I solved it by setting the correct module for the class in the inspector (see screenshot above).

Comment: Can someone answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959445/astoryboard-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifiermyid-returns-nil-but-not?noredirect=1#comment65274351_38959445

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
 + (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil.
```

So try this

```
self.storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Your_Story_Board_Name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
EntryViewController *entryController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"go"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:entryController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I used this answer to instantiate soryboard in AppDelegate. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

try this 
Storyboard Choose UIViewController-> Xcode->Editor->Emabed In->Navigation Controller

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];

YourViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"YourViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 UIStoryboard *    storyboardobj=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

 EntryViewController *entryController = [storyboardobj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"go"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:entryController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I was looking at another example like this, just tried yours and still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the view controllers `storyboard`. It's read only and set when the view controller is created. Instead, you will need to get the storyboard from somewhere else or load it.

You could get the storyboard from the AppDelegate's root view controller. Or use `+ (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil`.

Comment: It is not moving to the next view controller

Comment: And you checked that the storyboard was created by the call 'storyboardWithName:...'? And the view controller is instantiated for the 'go' identifier? And the current view is in a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, the storyboard im using is 'mainStoryboard" note the small m! The only thing is that im creating my view programmatically and although my view controller is embedded in a navigation controller when i run it in the emulator, no navigation bar appears at the top, do you think this is a problem?

Comment: its not crashing so its able to find the storyboard identifier however its not moving

Comment: can you show the code for how the original controller is created and is the navigation controller nil when you debug?

Comment: I just checked and the navigation controller is nil, i checked with a conditional statement 
    `if (self.navigationController == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Navigation controller is nil");
    }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31741/discussion-between-wain-and-teddyc)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue today, clearly set the Storyboard ID on the right panel but I was still getting the warnings that the VC was unreachable and did not have an identifier set. Fixed the issue after I unchecked the box that read "Inherit Module From Target" and ran the project.

[image]

After the code successfully ran, it seems to now work with or without the box checked so it might be an Xcode bug... Anyway hope this helps.