# Displaying modal views programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to be able to show a viewController when a button  is pressed.

I don't want to use a navigation controller anymore, is there a way to display it using a modal?

Here is how I am currently showing the viewController:

```
- (void) editButtonDidClicked: (UIButton *) button {
    EditViewController *viewController = [EditViewController getInstanceWithTag:button.tag];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code

**I assume that you are using storyboard.**

```
UIStoryboard *board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"name" bundle:nil];
viewController *controller = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"]; // Identifier is define in storyboard
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088057/instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-storyboard-id-set-but-still-not-workin) if you are still facing the problem.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: its coming up with a break point when the button is pressed still

Comment: did you add identifier in storyboard?