# Make Segue programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have two VCs: VC1 and VC2.
In VC1, I have a `finish button` which I programmatically made and a `result array` I want to pass to VC2.

I know how to make Segue in Storyboard, but I cannot do that at this moment since the `finish button` is programmatically made.

If I want to pass result array using segue, is there a way to make the segue programmatically? If this is not possible, should I just present VC2 using `presentViewController` and set a delegate to pass the `result array`?

Comment: You could create a segue in interface builder from VC1 to VC2, give it a name, then call `performSegueWithIdentifier` from the action you've got tied to the button. Then, in `prepareForSegue` you'd, put in an `if` statement IDing the segue you're using, grab whatever you're passing from VC1, assign it on VC2 and BAM...you're done.

Comment: Adrian, you should post this as an answer so the OP can accept it. This is the correct answer to the OPs question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it like proposed in this answer:
[InstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088057/instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-storyboard-id-set-but-still-not-workin).

Furthermore I am providing you the code from the linked answer rewritten in Swift because the answer in the link was originally written in Objective-C.

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier") as! SecondViewController

vc.resultsArray = self.resultsArray
```

**EDIT:**

Since this answer draws some attention I thought I provide you with another more failsafe way. In the above answer the application will crash if the `ViewController` with *"identifier"* is not of type `SecondViewController`. In Swift you can prevent this crash by using optional binding:

```
guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier") as? SecondViewController else {
    print("Could not instantiate view controller with identifier of type SecondViewController")
    return
}

vc.resultsArray = self.resultsArray
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
```

This way the `ViewController` is pushed if it is of type `SecondViewController`. If can not be casted to `SecondViewController` a message is printed and the application remains on the current `ViewController`.

Comment: Since the OP is asking about creating segues from a button action, creating a named `UIViewController` to `UIViewController` segue and invoking it with performSegueWithIdentifier, as suggested by @AdrianB, seems like a better solution.

Comment: @DuncanC made a good point but Dehlen's solution is also working :) I learned two different ways I guess.

Comment: Hi, this worked for me, but now when I click on cancel to navigate back, it doesn't work, any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you mean "Cancel" or "Back" ? Did you define your own IBAction for the "Cancel" action ? If so how does it look like ?

Answer (score 8):

You can still create the segue in Interface Builder by dragging from VC1 to VC2 - just drag from/to the little yellow circle at the top of the VC.  Give this segue a unique name in IB, and in your `finish` function you can call `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, pass in the name of your segue, and that's it.  In the `prepareForSegue` method you can find out which segue is being performed by accessing `segue.identifier`, and if it's the segue in question you can get a pointer to `segue.destinationViewController` and pass your data on that way.